# Sentence Structure in Math

Tags: sentence-structure

Here is the situation:

A math teacher (me) wrote on the board:

> 25% of an investment is accounted for $1500. Evaluate the amount of the investment.

An observer (another math teacher) mentioned afterwards that my sentence was a problem and needed to be more "defined". I asked the person what I should have written instead. He added the word **"as"** to the sentence:
"25% of an investment is accounted for **as** $1500."

Am I correct? Is he correct? Are we both correct?

or

Does the word "as" add anything to the sentence?

Comment: "25% of an investment is $1500. Evaluate the total amount of the investment." tests the maths and not an ability to decipher non-standard English.

Comment: I'm a math teacher, and I didn't understand what your question meant, with or without the addition of the word "as." Unlike  @Edwin Ashworth I thought that the total investment was $1500, and 25% of this was accounted… until I got to the next sentence, asking for the amount of the investment.

Comment: Why don't you just say "If 25% of an investment is $1,500, how much is the whole?"

Comment: I understood the question as written, immediately. The answer is $6,000.

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence appears to be a passivisation of "Something accounts for 25% of an investment $1500", which I can't parse because the $1500 has no grammatical role that I can find. It can't be the subject of "accounts for", and "accounts for" cannot take another argument. I suppose it could be in apposition to "an investment", but then I would expect it to be preceded by a comma (or "of").

I'm guessing that you actually meant it to be the passivisation of either "$1500 accounts for 25% of an investment", or "something accounts for 25% of an investment of $1500", but I'm not clear which.

Comment: ok, from your comments, I understand that the original question was at least ambiguous.  I actually meant the former "$1,500 accounts for 25% of an investment". But, does the word "as" add clarity?

Comment: I think it does, but I think _by_ would be clearer. Clearer still would be to turn the sentence round to make the principal the subject, or eliminate the confusing phrasal verb "account for". Eg "25% of an investment is $1500".

Comment: you made me understand what I did not understand - I felt that something was more wrong than "as", but I could not put my finger on it. tnx. +1

Comment: @gegu: where would you place "as" in the new sentence, to add clarity?

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the extra "the". I.E. Evaluate the investment (or invested) amount.

Comment: Addendum: If at all possible, do not use the same 'article' (the, a and an) in a sentence with the exception of duplication after a semicolon. Makes for a much 'cleaner' sentence, thus easier to comprehend/read.

Comment: As a general statement I disagree very strongly with this. It is good advice in many cases, but not all. Sometimes repeating an article will clarify rather than the reverse.

Comment: Colin Fine, please notice it is but a goal to limit repetitive articles within sentence structure, not a maxim. Having so stated, please provide a sentence where repetitive articles clarify, rather than 'muddy' intent. Thanks.